# Правильное написание марок машин

Tags: орфография, ономастика

Как правильно оформляются на письме марки машин?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насчет правописания марок автомобилей нет точного мнения и в разные годы были разные требования. Сейчас все склоняются к тому, чтобы писать марки машин с маленькой буквы, но в кавычках, за исключением тех случаев, когда название марки является именем собственным.
Пример: *"тойота", "ниссан", "Волга", "субару", "Ока"*.

Comment: Вообще-то правило получается нетривиальное. Волга и Ока - реки, в честь которых названы марки машин, поэтому они с прописной буквы. С другой стороны, все марки и названия фирм наверняка являются именами собственными, но тут я не эксперт. Ну, и в качестве примера приведу случай машины "мерседес" и напомню, что это название взялось из женского имени Мерседес. Так как писать?

Answer (score 2):

все названия машин в кавычках, но с прописной буквы.

Comment: Повторение первого ответа.

Comment: нет. Наоборот - возражение ему.