# Берутся ли в кавычки марки автомобилей?

Tags: ономастика, прописная-строчная, названия, кавычки

Не понимаю, берутся ли в кавычки марки автомобилей в подобных предложениях:
**Вы можете прокатиться на Тесле по Москве.**
Или:
**В 25 лет у него уже Инфинити.**

Comment: Подобные вопросы уже задавались: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/305/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%bd/306#306, https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/4801/%d0%9e-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8f

Comment: И еще: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/428337/%d0%92%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b8, https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/418974/%d0%a3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bb-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%85-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82/418982#418982

Answer (score 5):

Вот ответ с сайта "[Грамота.ру](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/75-kav2)":

Как свидетельствуют запросы пользователей нашего «Справочного бюро», особую сложность представляет написание названий автомобилей. Расскажем о них подробнее.

В полном академическом справочнике «Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации» под ред. В. В. Лопатина дана рекомендация писать названия марок автомобилей в кавычках с прописной буквы: автомобили «Волга», «Вольво», «Тойота», а названия самих автомобилей как технических изделий – со строчной буквы в кавычках (кроме названий, совпадающих с собственными именами – личными и географическими). Например: «москвич», «тойота», «вольво»,  но: «Волга», «Ока», «Таврия» (совпадают с именами собственными, поэтому пишутся с большой буквы). Исключения: «жигули», «мерседес» (совпадают с именами собственными, но пишутся со строчной). Однако на практике различить, в каком случае наименование представляет собой название марки автомобиля, а в каком – наименование технического изделия, часто представляется затруднительным: Всем автомобилям он предпочитает «Тойоту» / «тойоту». В спорных случаях решение о написании с прописной или строчной буквы принимает автор текста.

В бытовом употреблении названия средств передвижения пишутся со строчной буквы без кавычек, например: Приехал на стареньком москвиче (на роскошном кадиллаке). Без кавычек пишутся также разговорные названия машин с уменьшительно-ласкательными суффиксами, напр.: москвичок, фордик, уазик.

Аббревиатурные названия (сочетающиеся с номерами и без номеров) пишутся без кавычек: ЗИЛ, ВАЗ-2114, УАЗ, КамАЗ.

Неоднословные названия (марка и модель автомобиля), написанные кириллицей, заключаются в кавычки и пишутся через дефис, при этом все части наименования пишутся с прописной буквы: «Лада-Приора», «Тойота-Королла», «Рено-Меган», «Ниссан-Теана», «Хёндай-Гетц», «Ниссан-Альмера-Классик», «Сузуки-Гранд-Витара». Но: «Фольксваген-жук» (перекличка с нарицательным существительным).

Названия, написанные латиницей, в кавычки не заключаются: автомобили Toyota Yaris, Peugeot 306, Daewoo Matiz, Lada Priora.

---

Дополнение.

В названиях "Тесла" и "Инфинити" вы не можете опустить кавычки, так как у этих слов есть также иной, прямой смысл: Тесла - великий изобретатель, инфинити - бесконечность (а вариант *тесла* со строчной и без кавычек не подходит, так как в вашей фразе нет достаточно выраженного разговорного оттенка). Остается решить, использовать прописную или строчную букву.

Пишем "Тесла" с прописной, потому что назание совпадает с именем собственным:

**Вы можете прокатиться на "Тесле" по Москве.**

Для "Инфинити"/"инфинити" теоретически позможны оба варианта, но я бы выбрал первый. Во-первых, он всегда верен (в смысле, что у него автомобиль марки "Инфинити"); во-вторых, малознакомое слово, начинаюшееся со строчной буквы, может быть неверно истолковано.

**В 25 лет у него уже "Инфинити".**

Comment: Эту статью я читала, но так и не поняла - приведенные мною примеры относятся к "бытовому употреблению" или нет?

Comment: Я дополнил ответ.